# Old cID urls remain after migration

Tags: concrete5

I recently activated a domain for my website:

http://website.webfactional.com  —> http://website.com

The problem is all the internal urls (ex: website.webfactional.com/index.php?cID=277) have not been rewritten with the new address. How can I do this without manually editing each entry?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the [cache](http://yoursite.com/index.php/dashboard/system/optimization/cache)?

FYI - It's best to disable all caching before moving a site and setting it appropriately after the move.

Also, if you are running v7+ make sure your canonical URLs have your new website (not the old one - which should not be set during development).

You should also Enable Pretty URLs in the dashboard (and in .htaccess if you are running under an Apache server).

See [URLs and Redirection](http://yoursite.com/index.php/dashboard/system/seo/urls)

Comment: Yes, I did both (clearing cache & enabling pretty urls), but it's still the same. My version is 8.3.2.

Comment: Did you set the canonical URLs to the new website? Disable ALL caching? If it's not that, take a look at your .htaccess file. It might help posting a copy here. concrete5 does not store the website address anywhere else, unless it's overwritten in application/config/concrete.php - You are also probably better off posting this in the concrete5.org forum.

Comment: I did that too. I believe it is a bug actually, as documented here: https://www.concrete5.org/developers/bugs/8-3-2/express-rich-text-links-break-in-production/ It specifically happens in rich text areas.